# How can I match everything between 'ERA-00924' and the first '<' character with a Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

Given this input string:

```
String input = "some text ERA-00924: table does not exists</div";
```

How can I match everything between 'ERA-00924' and the first '<' character with a Java regular expression?

I am currently able to capture the 'ERA-00924' part with the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ERA-\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if( matcher.find() )
{
      String target = matcher.group();
}
```

But I am struggling to match all the way to the first '<' character (but not including).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
ERA-\\d{5}([^<]*)
```

And use group 1 for your value using:

```
matcher.group(1)
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  I am trying it now.

Comment: Yes that works!  It captures everything after the ERA-ddddd and before the first '<'.

I actually want to include the 'ERA-ddddd' as part of the group.

Can this be done as one group?  I apologize for the new question.